# Sort array every record should not repeated until it have more than one distinct values in it. Remainder values can be repeated any time

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array like this and want to sort it so that no record repeated till it have more than one distinc values in it.

```
 Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] => 1
[2] => 1
[3] => 1
[4] => 1
[5] => 2
[6] => 2
[7] => 2
[8] => 4
[9] => 4
)
```

I want the result array like this.

```
 Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] => 2
[2] => 4
[3] => 1
[4] => 2
[5] => 4
[6] => 1
[7] => 2
[8] => 1
[9] => 1
)
```

Thanks In advance..

Comment: Your desired output contains repetitions.

Comment: what if your input is `Array(1,1,1,2)`, what's the expected output then?

Comment: 1
2
1
1
Have corrected my question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```html
<?php
$array = array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1,
    5 => 2,
    6 => 2,
    7 => 2,
    8 => 4,
    9 => 4,
);

$newArray = array();
$i = 0;

while (count($array) > 0) {

    $newArray[$i] = array();
    
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

        if (!in_array($value, $newArray[$i])) {
            array_push($newArray[$i], $value);
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    sort($newArray[$i]);
    $i++;
}

$index = 0;
for ($j = 0; $j < count($newArray); $j++) {
    
    foreach ($newArray[$j] as $value) {
        $array[$index] = $value;
        $index++;
    }
}
?>
```